# Get conversation information from lync when own application is not started

Tags: c#, lync, lync-2010, lync-client-sdk

We want to import lync conversations in our business software. This is no problem if the software is started while starting conversations over lnyc. Is it possible, to get conversations which were made, during our application is not running? Like MS Outlook does under **Recorded Conversation**?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't beleave that you can with the Lync Client API.  It's really only for live data / control of the Lync Client.

There is the [Call detail recording (CDR) database](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398570%28v=ocs.15%29.aspx) if you want to list all Lync calls from a central place after the fact.

The [CDR](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/jj204621.aspx) needs to be enabled before it will start recording the call data out.